# Selenium: NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Tags: selenium

I am trying to write an exception test for [this page](http://www.behsad.com/nportal/Default.aspx?tabid=55):
Here is my pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-picocontainer -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is the code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("http://www.behsad.com/nportal/Default.aspx?tabid=55");

            driver.findElement(By.id("dnn_dnnUser_enhancedRegisterLink")).click();

            WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
            WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
                                            By.id("dnn_dnnUser_enhancedRegisterLink")));
            element.click();

            driver.switchTo().frame("iPopUp");
                driver.findElement(By.id("dnn_ctr_Register_userForm_Username_Username_TextBox"))
          .sendKeys("Hey");
```

**The problem is it goes to the right place, but it doesn't do anything. it stucks in this level**

I am sure, **i have asked for a valid id** which is 
 `dnn_ctr_Register_userForm_Username_Username_TextBox` but can any of you tell me why it cannot write the `Hey`?

Update: this line

```
driver.findElement(By.id("dnn_dnnUser_enhancedRegisterLink")).click();
```

clicks on this button[image]

and then this page should get loaded[image]

Answer (score 3):

Before answering your problem, let me point out that when the browser opens up the page, it takes some time for the page to load. When it's loading, your script tries to find the element with id `dnn_dnnUser_enhancedRegisterLink`. In some cases it may fail when searching for this element, so I suggest you add a wait for the element to become visible. Try this:

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
                                By.id("dnn_dnnUser_enhancedRegisterLink")));
element.click();
```

Now after clicking the element, there is a popup which appears. That popup is inside an `iframe`, so you need to switch Selenium's focus to that before searching for the element with id `dnn_ctr_Register_userForm_Username_Username_TextBox`. The `iframe`'s id is `iPopUp`, so do this before searching for the element:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("iPopUp");
```

So the final code should be this:

```
driver.get("http://www.behsad.com/nportal/Default.aspx?tabid=55");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
                                 By.id("dnn_dnnUser_enhancedRegisterLink")));
element.click();
driver.switchTo().frame("iPopUp");
WebElement searchElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
                By.id("dnn_ctr_Register_userForm_Username_Username_TextBox")));
searchElement.sendKeys("Hey");
```

Comment: Yes, you can adjust it the way you want. btw I made more changes to my answer

Comment: I got it. So even the popup takes some time to load. You need to wait for the input field to become visible too. I have made the changes in my code by adding a wait before typing "hey"

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.until`

Comment: Did you add the import statement for `WebDriver`? What version of selenium are you using?

Comment: yes, i did it with `import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;`.i have added the dependency to question

Comment: That's not the part that's missing.  You probably see a red line under your until statement.  Hover the mouse cursor there, and it should suggest the proper import.  @Jayesh Doolani's solution is correct.  If you haven't already done so, remove the extra findelements at the start - it's not in the solution and redundant.

Comment: @BillHileman is it possible OP might be using the latest version of selenium in which `FluentWait` was deprecated?

Comment: Come to think of it, that may be it.  Good point.  I had encountered the same thing recently.  The solution I used was to put my selenium back to the previous version.  I know I tried 3.4.0 but I did not try every version in between (3.0-3.3)  I went back to 2.53

Comment: I was told all I needed to do was update guava, and I did, to version 21, but it made no difference for me.

Comment: @BillHileman Are you sure FluentWait got deprecated. Though I am yet to use FluentWait in Selenium 3.4.0 but I saw a lot of questions around it. I feel it's​ still in the business. Thanks

Comment: It is not actually deprecated, but its implementation has changed in that it no longer supports ExpectedConditions and makes code using that method no longer work. I do not fully understand the new implementation (yet) and none of the examples I found worked for elelmentIsClickable.

Answer (score 0):

I'd open up the page in a browser and using the console try to get the element with javascript:

```
document.getElementById("dnn_ctr_Register_userForm_Username_Username_TextBox")
```

just to make sure you are correct about the id existing.

Comment: but my question is, why selenium fail to open it?

Comment: My experience is that it would if it exists which is why I suggest making sure it does via javascript. Is it possible it is in an iFrame on the page? If so, you may have to switch contexts in the driver to the iframe.